# Trying to uncompress my word list

Tags: python

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sentence= ("ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

lst = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))
numberLst = []
for i in words:
    numberLst.append(lst.index(i)+1)

print(lst)
print (numberLst)

words_str = ''.join(words)
numberLst_str = ''.join(str(e) for e in numberLst)

file = open("words.txt","w")
file.write(words_str)
file.close()

file=open("numberlst.txt","w")
file.write(numberLst_str)
file.close()
```

I am trying to decompress a list of words that I have already compressed in my code above.I have succeeded in compressing the words found in the sentence, however I do not know how to decompress this list and put the words back into their original positions in the sentence.

Comment: `"As seen"`? Where? I don't see any output.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> " ".join(lst[x-1] for x in numberLst)
'ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country'
```

It simply builds the list of words then joins them into a single sentence.